# 5 chess pieces dominating a 5x5 grid

Tags: combinatorics, chess

This is a puzzle based on work by Rodolfo Kurchan.

Can you place a pawn, a knight, a bishop, a rook and a king on a 5x5 chess grid, such that every empty cell is attacked by at least one piece? Note that the pawn attacks the two diagonal cells directly above it.

Comment: Are there any more solutions?

Comment: Is it possible to solve 5x6?

Comment: If you give another knight, it's possible. I think with the original ones it's not possible. In my answer if you move the rook down one row, and switch the knight to the square it currently is attacking, only 2 squares are uncovered though. If you replaced the king with queen, you can almost cover 6x6

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This arrangement of pieces should work:

> [image]

Comment: Ah, jou beat me in only 1 minute. Well done :)

Comment: @Lezzup thanks :) I would've submitted it faster if not for the restriction that I need to have at least 30 characters aside from the image XD "This should work" -> "This arrangement should work" -> "This arrangement of pieces should work" lol

Comment: Technically, the square with the knight is nobody attacking. But in my solution I've got the same problem with the square where the king is located. I am not sure if there is a better answer? ;)

Comment: The puzzle only requires that every "empty cell" be attacked. Those occupied are not empty cells. (Oh, and someone just noticed, and I just noticed too, that your rook doesn't attack the left-most blue square, blocked by pawn)

Answer (score 9):

<strike>This also works:</strike>

> [image]
>  r = rook, p = pawn, kn = knight, ki = king, b = bishop

Thanks @justhalf, this is works:

> [image]

Comment: The knight covers a lot of squares, cool :D

Comment: @Lezzup you can fix it by moving the rook to the other side (shifting everything to the right). This way, the knight will be the center piece

Comment: FYI, the standard practice is to use N for knight and K for king, so you don't have to use a second letter to distinguish them.

Comment: This is the only answer so far that is significantly different from my answer (rook on a corner, the rest covering 4x4 area similarly), nice one.

Answer (score 9):

Came up with an alternative solution from the other answers

> [image]

Answer (score 5):

Others have solved this similarly, but here's mine.

> [image: my solution: Ra5, Nd4, Kc2, Bd2, Pd3]

Comment: f1 and f2 are both not covered here :)

Comment: The Board here is not **5x5** , it is **5x6** , @GeorgeWilson , hence that "uncovered" area !!

Comment: I tricked you with my terrible screenshotting (-:

Comment: fixed the diagram.

Comment: @Evargalo Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution.

> Another variant of the bishop-pawn-knight tower
>
>  [image: My solution: Nc5 c4 Bc3 Kb2 Re1]